# Structure of a Vector Space through ring homomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

My question is:

Suppose we have a ring homomorphism from $\mathbb Z$ to any finite field $F$ whose kernel is $p\mathbb Z$ (say).
Now this ring homomorphism induces another ring homomorphism $h:\mathbb Z / p\mathbb Z\to F$.
My question is how this new homomorphism $h$ gives $F$ a structure of a vector space over the field $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$?

Comment: Hint: add dollar signs around your equations (as I've done for the first) to make them appear as math. You'll need to write "\mathbb Z" rather than "\mathbbZ", though -- the space is essential.

Comment: @JohnHughes $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field... Also, the $p$ in this problem is not just any $p$. In order for the kernel to be of the form $p\mathbb{Z}$, $p$ must be the characteristic of $F$ (assuming, of course, that $p$ is prime).

Comment: Exactly!! @ ken Duna

Answer (score 1):

Define map $\varphi\colon\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z\to \operatorname{End}(F)$ with $\bar n\mapsto(x\mapsto h(\bar n)x)$. Verify that $x\mapsto h(\bar n)x$ really is additive so the map is well-defined and that $\varphi$ is ring homomorphism that preserves unit. This defines ring action of $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ on $F$, and thus $F$ is $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ vector space.

Alternatively, define multiplication by scalar with $\bar n\cdot x = h(\bar n)x$ and verify vector space axioms.

Answer (score 1):

For $c \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ and $a \in F$, define the scalar multiplication to be $c\cdot a = h(c)a.$ You should check that this is a well-defined scalar multiplication.

Any finite field is a finite-dimensional vector space over its prime subfield. Here, you have embedded $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ into $F$ as its prime subfield.

Comment: U mean to say that F here is considered as a vector space over the field f($\mathbb Z$/(p$\mathbb Z$))

Comment: And that's why it's cardinality will be a power of 'p'.

Comment: @SumitMittal Exactly!

Comment: Okay I got it! And thanxx a lot..

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$$\renewcommand{\phi}{\varphi}$$\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}$Perhaps it is useful to rephrase first the axioms of vector spaces in the following manner.

Let $V$ be an abelian group, and $K$ a field. Let $\End(V)$ be the ring of endomorphisms of $V$.

Then a structure of a $K$-vector space on $V$ is equivalent to a homomorphism of rings with unity $\phi : K \to \End(V)$. In fact, if you have such a structure, and $\lambda v$ denote scalar multiplication of $v \in V$ by $\lambda \in K$, then $\phi(\lambda) = (v \mapsto \lambda v)$ defines such a homomorphism. And conversely if one has such a homomorphism, then defining $\lambda v = (\phi(\lambda)) (v)$ yields a vector space structure.

So in your case $F$ is an abelian group. If $a \in \Z$, the map $v \mapsto a v$ (where $a v$ is the $a$-th multiple of $v \in F$) is an endomorphism of the abelian group $F$, and the map $\Z \mapsto (v \mapsto a v)$ is a homomorphism of rings with unity $\Z \to \End(F)$, which has kernel $p \Z$, and thus yields as you note a homomorphism of rings with unity $\Z/p\Z \to \End(F)$.